# Helper to fix errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

I started to use `Android Studio` and I am looking for the option to fix errors similar to `Eclipse IDE`.

For example, in `Eclipse`, if you have some code that might `throw` an `exception` `Eclipse` shows you an option to surround the code with a `try/catch` statement, so you don't have to write it manually.

In `Android Studio` I can't find this option and it's very frustating for me because in `Eclipse` it was so fast to do this and here I have to do it manually.

Anybody knows how to do this in `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was looking for is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> and it shows you all the fixes available.

Answer (score 1):

**for** *windows*

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

**for** *Mac*

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

you will find different `android studio` tips on this [link](http://www.developerphil.com/android-studio-tips-of-the-day-roundup-1/)

Comment: that works for try/catch but to do a cast for example it doesn't. It seems it's another option and I don't find the keyboard shortcut to do it, like in eclipse with ctrl + f1. Do you know it?